# Displaying data in ListView in WinApi

Tags: c, winapi

I use a function named `print_base()` to set all elements from an array of struct in each field of a ListView:

```
void print_base(int number_of_students) {
    int test_value = 3;
    int exam_value= 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++) {
            switch(j){
                case 0:
                    char buffer_ID[50];
                    sprintf (buffer_ID, "%d ",student[i].ID );
                    ListView_InsertItem(grade_list, &lvi);
                    lvi.pszText = buffer_ID;
                    lvi.iItem = i;
                    lvi.iSubItem = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, j, student[i].name);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, j,student[i].surname);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    char buffer_mark1 [50];
                    sprintf (buffer_mark1 , "%d ",student[i].mark_1 );
                    ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, j, buffer_mark1 );
                    break;
                case 4:
                    char buffer_mark2 [50];
                    sprintf (buffer_mark2 , "%d ",student[i].mark_2 );
                    ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, j,buffer_mark2 );
                    break;
                case 5:
                    char buffer_mark3 [50];
                    sprintf (buffer_mark3 , "%d ",student[i].mark_3 );
                    ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, j, buffer_mark3 );
                    break;
                case 6:
                    char buffer_mark4 [50];
                    sprintf (buffer_mark4 , "%d ",student[i].mark_4 );
                    ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, j,buffer_mark4 );
                    break;
                case 7:
                    student[i].avarage=((((float)student[i].mark_1*test_value)+(student[i].mark_2*test_value)+(student[i].mark_3*test_value)+(student[i].mark_4*exam_value))/14);
                    char buffer_avarage[50];
                    sprintf (buffer_avarage, "%.2f ",student[i].avarage);
                    ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, j, buffer_avarage);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why, but as you can see in the picture below, only the last record is shown almost properly (no ID).  avarage is not seen because the ListView scales:

[image]

I think there might be a problem with `ListView_InsertItem()`, but I don't know what is wrong exactly.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and how to fix it?

In addition, I would like to know if there is any possibility to edit and save changes done in the ListView (double-click and edit one field or something).

Comment: you not try initialize `lvi` *before* call `ListView_InsertItem` but not *after* ? sometimes this help. this is main point.

Comment: Not it this case. I have tried both options.

LVITEM lvi;
lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
print_base(amount_of_students);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-initialize the `LVITEM` on each iteration of the outer loop, and you need to initialize its fields *before* calling `ListView_InsertItem()`.

And there is no need to use an inner loop at all, that is just wasted coding.

Try something more like this instead:

```
void print_base(int number_of_students)
{
    int test_value = 3;
    int exam_value = 4;

    LVITEM lvi;
    char buffer[50];

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; ++i)
    {
        memset(&lvi, 0, sizeof(lvi));
        lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
        lvi.iItem = i;
        lvi.iSubItem = 0;
        lvi.pszText = buffer;

        sprintf(buffer, "%d", student[i].ID);
        ListView_InsertItem(grade_list, &lvi);

        ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, 1, student[i].name);
        ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, 2, student[i].surname);

        sprintf(buffer, "%d", student[i].mark_1);
        ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, 3, buffer);

        sprintf(buffer, "%d", student[i].mark_2);
        ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, 4, buffer);

        sprintf(buffer, "%d", student[i].mark_3);
        ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, 5, buffer);

        sprintf(buffer, "%d", student[i].mark_4);
        ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, 6, buffer);

        student[i].average = ((((float)student[i].mark_1 * test_value) + (student[i].mark_2 * test_value) + (student[i].mark_3 * test_value) + (student[i].mark_4 * exam_value)) / 14);

        sprintf(buffer, "%.2f", student[i].avarage);
        ListView_SetItemText(grade_list, i, 7, buffer);
    }
}
```

As for editing, the ListView only supports editing the first column (see the [`LVS_EDITLABELS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739.aspx) window style, and the [`ListView_EditLabel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761238.aspx) window message).  When editing is complete, the ListView will send a [`LVN_ENDLABELEDIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774814.aspx) notification to its parent window containing the item index and new text, which you can then copy into your `student[]` array.

If you want to allow editing the other column values, you are better off using a different UI for that, such as an [`EDIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458.aspx) control and a Save [`BUTTON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775943.aspx).  When the user clicks on a ListView item, you can copy the desired column text into the `EDIT` control, and when the button is clicked then copy the new text back into the array and update the ListVew accordingly.

Comment: *"You need to re-initialize the `LVITEM` on each iteration of the outer loop"* - Alternatively, place it inside the loop: `LVITEM lvi = { 0 };`. There's no practical reason to declare a variable in a wider scope than it's designated life time.